# Rotativa doesn't recognize foreignobject tag when use it in SVG?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, rotativa

I'm trying to convert html to PDF using [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa) I'm building the report as svg tag in html page and pass the generated view to Rotativa, it prints almost every thing except what's inside  (which is here  and

):

```
<svg style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" height="1453" width="1040" y="0" x="0">
<switch>
    <foreignObject x="49" y="215" width="943" height="500" class="s2_2" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        
            <p style="line-height: 25px;">
                Any words here
            </p>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="styled-table">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th class="s3_2">Full Name</th>
                    <th class="s3_2">Source</th>
                    <th class="s3_2">Date of Birth</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caroline Ashcrof</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                    <td>dd/mm/yyyy</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caroline Ashcrof</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                    <td>dd/mm/yyyy</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caroline Ashcrof</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
                    <td>dd/mm/yyyy</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </foreignObject>
</switch>
```

I upgraded wkhtmltopdf.exe in rotativa to latest version (0.13) with no luck.
Is there a solution, workaround or even another module to convert html to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but attribute "requiredExtensions" shouldn't be added when using Rotativa and want to convert to PDF